# Python regex. How to exclude lines with period+slash at the end

Tags: python, regex

```
((http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9.\-]{3,253}[/\'])
```

What i need to add to exclude something like google.com./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[^.]` (not `.`) before matching the last character (/ or '):

```
((http|https)://{2,252}[^.][/\'])
```

Also reduce by 1 the lower and upper length range for the `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]` set to `{2,252}`.